# Migrate Postrges to MySQL special characters

Tags: mysql, postgresql, utf-8, migration, database-migration

I'm tyring to migrate a PostgreSQL database to MySQL using the MySQL Workbench Migration wizard.

The source database is UTF8 (and so is the destination DB). But it has a problem converting latin characters like ('é', 'ü' etc). The migration tool tries to insert them as \xe9 (for instance) and throws an error on that.

Is there an easy way to fix them (without me having to update every single text field in the source db to replace all possible instances of these characters)

Comment: Did you state that the source was latin1 and the destination was utf8?

Comment: both source & destination are UTF8. I eventually gave up and found another method :)